# Transponer filas de meses a columnas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, mysqldb

Estoy desarrollando una consulta a una tabla en MySQL, pero no logro tener el resultado.

**Aquí un fiddle de la tabla que tengo:**

[fiddle de la tabla](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/et9TXrkf33L3wcHh6u6m8f/0)

Como se puede observar en la ejecución, tengo 5 campos (cuenta, valor, **mes**, año, empresa) y lo que deseo hacer es que los valores de la columna **mes** (1,2,3,4,5,6...) se traspongan como columnas y que como registro de cada una se coloque el campo **valor** asociado, para que dé como resultado algo así.

[image: resultado ejemplo]

La cuenta juega un valor importante, porque en realidad se agruparía y formaría un solo row.

He leido en varios foros cómo hacer lo que quiero, pero no he podido dar con el "chiste".

Comment: prueba utilizando outer apply

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¿Puedes explicarme como lo haría?

Comment: @anonimo ¿Qué opinas, hay alguna forma más corta? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/et9TXrkf33L3wcHh6u6m8f/1

Comment: Solo la coloqué como referencia, pero la verdad no la necesito para la vista, ese campo empresa se guarda desde la aplicación, para diferenciar : ejemplo : buscame estos datos del mes X al mes Y  del año Z y que sean de dicha empresa (hay muchas empresas diferentes), pero en la vista no la necesito mostrar.

Comment: pues bueno creo que mas o menos llegamos a lo mismo, aquí te dejo como me salió a mi [tabla pivote](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/et9TXrkf33L3wcHh6u6m8f/0)

Comment: No puedo ver tu tabla, me muestra mi ejercicio (el primero que hice) da clic en actualizar y me envias el link. please.

Comment: disculpa me equivoque de link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b59UanE1QFMbU7F1ete38h/0

Comment: ¿Porqué te funciona con SUM, y a mi tambien me funciona pero con MAX?

Comment: si no me equivoco, muestra lo mismo por que por cada grupo de los 2 renglones que te salen solo hay 1 registro numérico para cada mes por lo tanto solo me muestra la cantidad numérica que existe; ejemplo: en el primer renglón encuentra 12000 y nada mas entonces la función `SUM` no tiene nada mas que sumarle y devolverá ese valor @JuanD

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución se encontraba en trabajar con **tablas pivote**.
Dejo el fiddle de la solución:

[Fiddle, solución a problema](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/et9TXrkf33L3wcHh6u6m8f/1)

```
-- Crear Tabla

create table historico (cuenta int,valor decimal(20,2),mes int,anio int, empresa varchar(30));

-- Insertar Datos

INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, -5173740.00, 1, 2017, "SERVICIOS S.A.S");
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 2, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 3, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 4, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 5, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 6, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 7, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 8, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 987444.60, 9, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 10, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 11, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110505, 0.00, 12, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 700000.00, 1, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 2, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 3, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 4, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 5, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 6, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 7, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 8, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 9, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 10, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 11, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
INSERT INTO historico  VALUES (110510, 0.00, 12, 2017, 'SERVICIOS S.A.S');
```

-- Solución:

```
SELECT
    cuenta,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 1 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS enero,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 2 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS febrero,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 3 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS marzo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 4 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS abril,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 5 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS mayo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 6 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS junio,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 7 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS julio,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 8 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS agosto,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 9 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS septiembre,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 10 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS octubre,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 11 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS noviembre,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mes = 12 THEN valor ELSE '' END) AS diciembre 
FROM
    historico
WHERE anio = 2017 AND mes BETWEEN 01 and 12
GROUP BY cuenta
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Logre esto:
index.php:

```
<?php


require "conexion.php";

if($conexion->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Error de conexion de la base datos".$conexion->connect_error;
    exit();
}
$sql = "select * from historico"; //seleccionamos todo lo que contenga la base de datos

$resultado = $conexion->query($sql); //guardamos los resultados en una variable
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">LISTADO HISTORICO</h1>
    <table width="70%" border="1px" align="center">

    <tr align="center">
        <td>Cuenta</td>
        <td>Enero</td>
        <td>Febrero</td>
        <td>Marzo</td>
        <td>Abril</td>
        <td>Mayo</td>
        <td>Junio</td>
        <td>Julio</td>
        <td>Agosto</td>
        <td>Septiembre</td>
        <td>Octubre</td>
        <td>Noviembre</td>
        <td>Diciembre</td>
        <td>Empresa</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
       //Recogemos los datos 
        while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <?php
                echo '<td>'.$datos["cuenta"].'</td>';
               //Usamos if para comprar el número de el mes de la tabla, si este es igual a 1, pinta un td con el valor de enero
                if($datos["mes"] == "1"){
                    echo '<td>.$datos["valor"].''</td>';
                }
                //De lo contrario (else) solo pone un td con el valor de 0
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "2"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "3"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "4"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "5"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "6"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "7"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "8"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "9"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "10"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "11"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                if($datos["mes"] == "12"){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
                echo '<td>'.$datos["empresa"].'</td>';
                ?>
            </tr>
            <?php   
        }

     ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Conexion.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //Tu host
$user = "root"; //Nombre de usuario de mysql
$pass = ""; //Contraseña de mysql
$db = "registrohistorico"; //Nombre de la base de datos
$conexion = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué comentario anterior? Pd: acabo de editar el código comentando el funcionamiento del mismo

Comment: muchas gracias por el codigo, en realidad no es necesario editar la pregunta que hice, puesto que no lo necesito desde la capa de aplicación, sino desde los datos. muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: No me di cuenta que me faltó una td! Ya te edito el código, disculpa estaba apurado y por eso quedó así... Si resolví tu duda porfavor dale a la palomita a mí respuesta (es para decir que ya se respondió la pregunta y así yo recibir unos puntos por ayudarte) se encuentra a la izquierda donde están las flechitas hacia arriba o abajo

Comment: Mirando mejor... Creo que mal entendí tu pregunta, podrías mostrar otra imagen de cómo quieres que quede? Me sería útil para editar el código y dejarlo como lo necesitas

Comment: en la pregunta esta la imagen de lo que busca obtener

Comment: Vaaale, ahora sí, creo que ahora ya está bien hecho, andaba con la cabeza en otro lado haha, espero ahora te funcione correctamente @JuanD

Answer (score 0):

pasaba por aca y vi el tremendo derroche de código jajaja...

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
                if($datos["mes"] == $i){
                    echo '<td>'.$datos["valor"].'</td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                };
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes.
Para que tu respuesta quede mejor te recomiendo añadir una explicacion sobre lo que hace tu codigo